# Не могу создать WinForms C++ проект в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, winforms

Всем привет.
Создаю проект Winforms C++.
Делаю так:
1. Создаю пустой CLR проект
2. Добавлю в свой проект Windows Forms форму
Но тут возникает проблема
Вместо конструктора вылазает такое окно с ошибкой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Закрой/открой файл. Если не поможет, то студию целиком перезапусти

Comment: Хм, а как теперь заново открыть конструктор?

Comment: _как теперь заново открыть конструктор?_ - дважды кликните по файлу MyForm.h.

Answer (score 0):

Поддержка конструктора WinForms была удалена давным-давно в VS 2012. WinForms можно добавить только с использованием С++/CLI.

Первый вариант - добавить WinForms с помощью C++/CLI [данным методом](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e6fbde42-d872-4ab3-8000-41ab22a4a584/visual-studio-2017-windows-forms?forum=winformsdesigner) , второй - скачать VS 2012 или ниже.